# Firefox Right-click Context Menus Background

Tags: firefox

When I right-click in Firefox my menus are grey with a slightly darker grey for the font which is difficult to read. Is there a way to manually edit the background colors of these menus?

Comment: Change your theme. Or create a new one. Search "Create custom Firefox Theme"

Answer (score 0):

You can change EVERYTHING in Firefox - it is open source software after all, and you can make it dance on its head, if you are so inclined. But if you don't feel like poking through code, just change your theme. Find something brighter - there are plenty to choose from.

Comment: Okay maybe I should be more clear. Can anyone tell me how to change the background color in the Firefox context menus. I was hoping someone might have already poked around and figured this out. I don't really want to change my theme because everything else is perfect about it. I use the Nasa Night Launch theme which colors even the status bar. Personas don't do that for me... unless they have updated them sometime recently to do so.

Comment: If that's the case, take a look at http://www.mozilla.org/unix/customizing.html. You can customize the CSS that controls the look and feel of your browser's chrome - but you have to know what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I looked into some of the options there and will probably have to do a lot more digging before I figure it out. It lists quite a few ui options under color look-and-feel prefs, but I didn't see where it explains what they do yet or how to use them. If I figure it out I will post it back here.

Comment: I don't think themes can customize the background of context menus, can they? I didn't find one that did at least. Therefor I think chrome.css is the only answer, besides operating system's (Windows,..) properties, because context menu is also (or soly?) determined by windows.